# Foreign key mvc 4 code first c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can i add a foreign key to a Model (code first)

i have a model Product which has an ID (primary key) which i want to add to my model order like.

```
public class Order
{
 public int ID {get; set;}

 [Required]
 public int Total {get; set;}    

 [Required]
 public int ProductId{get; set;}
}
```

but how can i make the ProductId refer to the id of my Product model like a foreign key?
On Stackoverflow there are alot simmilar questions but all with different answers, but they arent working for me. I really hope someone has a solution or can points me in the right direction with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a navigation property:

```
public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
```

So the Order class will look like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public int Total {get; set;}    

    [Required]
    public int ProductId{get; set;}

    [Required]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Also, strictly speaking the `ProductId` property isn't needed once you have the virtual Product property.

Comment: Thanks i will try it, can you explain why there is 2 X Product ? it seems odd to me, i saw it in other examples but i dont understand why.

Comment: The first is the type (i.e. your `Product` model) and the second is just the name of the property.

Comment: thanks, does that mean i could name it public virtual Product ForeignProduct

Comment: Yes, anything you like! :)

Comment: Thanks it worked, one last question :P i generated the crud files, on create there is no option to select an existing room (i kinda expted it to auto-generate because they know it is a foreign key) Where should i link the product to the order  ?

Comment: What is a crud file? And a room?

Comment: room should be product ( i used room in my project, product was easyer to understand in the example) crud create read update delete. the pages you can autogenerate when creating a controller. (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller ) is what i was using for generation of crud files.

Comment: That's a bit more complicated than I have time for right now unfortunately (it's almost midnight and I need my beauty sleep!)

Comment: no probelem thanks for the help, i was stuck ! have a good night.

Comment: What do you mean by select an existing room?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
public class Order
{
 public int ID {get; set;}

 [Required]
 public int Total {get; set;}    

 [Required]
 public int ProductId{get; set;}

 [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
 public virtual Product Product {get; set;}

}
```